# C++ MiniDumpWriteDump failed

Tags: c++, dump

I am trying to create a simple C++ console app which dump the memory space of a given process (e.g. calc.exe) So I use [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function

Here is the code :

```
DWORD procID = 1150;
char* procName = "calc.exe";

    // opens the dump file
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( "calc.dmp", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL ); 
    if(hFile)
    {
        // opens the process
        HANDLE hProcToDump = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE,  procID);
        if(hProcToDump)
        {
            // dumps via the API
            BOOL rv = MiniDumpWriteDump(hProcToDump, GetProcessId(hProcToDump), hFile, MiniDumpNormal, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            HRESULT hr = GetLastError();

            if( !rv )
                printf("MiniDumpWriteDump failed.");
            else
                printf("Minidump OK!");

            CloseHandle( hFile );
            CloseHandle( hProcToDump );
        }
}
```

But I get the error :
**GetLastError() = hresult 0x8007012b Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed**

Why ?
Note : I am admin on Win 7 x64.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried supplying a `*MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION` object instead of the 1st `NULL` argument when calling `MiniDumpWriteDump` in order to get more details about the error?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what to set for "ThreadId : The identifier of the thread throwing the exception." I don't have any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is similar to your example. [Usage of MiniDumpWriteDump](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/05/19/prolific-usage-of-minidumpwritedump-automating-crash-dump-analysis-part-0.aspx).

Comment: Exactly the same error with the example you gave me.